# Django ignores TIME_ZONE when USE_TZ = True

Tags: django, timezone

I have this field:

```
needed_on = SplitDateTimeField(
        input_date_formats=['%m/%d/%Y', ],
        input_time_formats=settings.TIME_INPUT_FORMATS,
        localize=True,
        label=_("At")
    )
```

And Django settings :

```
TIME_ZONE = 'US/Pacific'

USE_TZ = True
```

My template :

```
<div class="field_parent">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="on" class="date" id="datepicker1" name="needed_on_0" value="{{ form.needed_on.value|default_if_none:''|first }}" />
                </div>
                <div class="field_parent">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="{% trans "HH:mm" %}" class="time" id="id_needed_on_1" name="needed_on_1"  value="{{ form.needed_on.value|default_if_none:""|last }}" />
                </div>
```

Yet, I get time printed in UTC. 
What am I doing wrong?

### Thanks.

Edit `{{form.needed_on.value}}` returns `('10/30/2015', '09:25 AM')` so I don't think it's a string.

Comment: Well what might happen is that in your template you receive not date value but just a string.
You can check that localization actually works by passing date value to the template and check how it displays.

Comment: Shouldn't the date be processed in the form side ? at __init__ ?

Comment: Edited the question. It's not a string, it's a tuple that has no attribute 'tzinfo'